# can't knit markdown because plot.new hasn't been called

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to knit a markdown document in r for a class. I'm using the maps package because that is required, but when I try to knit the document, I get this error:

```
Quitting from lines 20-25 (Assignment-13b.Rmd) 
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> points -> points.default -> plot.xy
Execution halted
```

The chunk that line 20 is in is this one:

```
cities <- data.frame(lon = c(-112.1860,-110.9747,-110.0676,-111.6513,-112.1266), lat=c(33.5387,32.2226,31.7129,35.1983,35.9736), names=c("Glendale", "Tuscon", "Tombstone", "Flagstaff","Tusayan"), pop=c(246709,525677,1296,71975,583));
map('county', 'Arizona')
points(cities, cex=log(cities$pop, base=1000), col="red", pch=19)
text(cities$lon, cities$lat, cities$names, pos = 1)
title("Five Cities in Arizona")
```

Line 20 starts with the "map" function. As far as I can tell, it breaks because after map, all of the code must be run while the graphics window is still open, but knit closes the window after the map function. How can I knit this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was something in the tidyverse (which I loaded earlier in the file) that was causing the error. Not sure what, but when loading just the packages I absolutely needed, it worked fine.